# Azure VM Networking Issue

Tags: virtual-machine, azure, licensing

Long time reader, first time asker...

So, here is my situation:

I am consulting for a company for a azure migration project. For some reason, even though I have confirmed with several sources, I have been tasked with proving that I can create a VM on the on-prem Hyper-V server without licensing it and then copy that VHD to Azure and create a VM from it. I will spare you the steps that I have followed to get it up to the cloud, it is pretty basic. What I am facing now is that once I have created the snapshot and disk and spun up the VM, I get ZERO outbound network traffic. Meaning I am unable to connect via RDP. I have tried just about everything under the sun. I even went back on-prem to see if there was an issue with the NIC there....NOPE, I am able to get out to internet and everything.

If anyone could assist with this, maybe have some leading questions that would point me somewhere I haven't thought of yet, that'd be great!

ryan

Comment: Have you adjusted the IP address(es) on the VM to be compatible with the network(s) its new host is on?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if there are inbound security rules denying the rdp traffic in the **network security group** in you VM virtual network.

For more details on windows, please follow this link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/troubleshoot-rdp-connection

For more details on linux, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/detailed-troubleshoot-ssh-connection

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wasn't paying attention to this question....

it would appear that since i was a contractor and not assigned to the correct VLAN in the office, i could not RDP outside.....

I was able to test and prove this.